# SQL Error when importing stock csv

Tags: magento2, import, csv, stock

Since we have updated to magento 2.4.6 when we want to import stock via csv we now receive an error.

systemException
Additional data: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 2, query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `cp_table`.`type_id` FROM `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `main_table` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `cp_table` ON main_table.product_id = cp_table.entity_id WHERE (`main_table`.`website_id` = '0') AND (`main_table`.`product_id` IN())</div

Does anybody have any idea what this could be?

No plugins have changed or anything like that since the upgrade. We upgraded from 2.4.5 to 2.4.6

the example import csv file is like the below

[image]

Thanks
Mike

Comment: are you trying direct SQL query Or getting error in admin ?

Comment: Hey, we are getting this error in the admin/backend section of the website.